# how to replace between two files with awk or sed?

Tags: awk

I have file1:

```
7   8   pos
0/0 0/1 1
1/1 0/1 2
0/1 ./. 3
./. 0/1 4
0/1 0/1 5
```

and file2:

```
7   8   pos
0|0 0|1 1
1|1 1|0 2
0|1 1|0 3
1|1 1|0 4
0|1 0|1 5
```

I wish to replace all entries in `file2` in which there is a `./.` in the same position in `file1` with a `./.`

So I would obtain the following file:

```
7   8   pos
0|0 0|1 1
1|1 1|0 2
0|1 ./. 3
./. 1|0 4
0|1 0|1 5
```

I tried using:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ for (i=1;i<=2) { if ($i=="./.") { print NR, NF } }  }' file1
```

to get the coordinates of all instances of `./.`, but `NF` just prints the total number of fields, not the field matching a particular condition.

Nonetheless, the above code would be highly inefficient as I would have to then cross-match the positions and then replace.

If anyone could please guide me to more efficient solution, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Would replacing all `/` by `|` except for the `./.` case in your file1 give the requested result ?

Comment: @JohnBéjot, no unfortunately not. The order of the 1's and 0's on either side of the `|` in `file2` must be conserved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { tgt = "./." }
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ($i == tgt) {
            hit[FNR,i]=1
        }
    }
    next
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        if ( hit[FNR,i] ) {
            $i = tgt
        }
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
7   8   pos
0|0 0|1 1
1|1 1|0 2
0|1 ./. 3
./. 1|0 4
0|1 0|1 5
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please explain the `hit[FNR,i]=1` portion of the script. I understand you created an array indexed by `FNR`, but why is it set equal to `1`?

Comment: That sets it when reading the first file so that in the subsequent block of code when reading the 2nd file you can test for it being set (`if ( hit[FNR,i] )`).